# Update row in DataTables table without refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

I have a problem with my script.

In my table, every row has a url link which open modal window with email input to change this email without refresh page.

Script is ok if you change only one row. If I change second, third, etc row, every values changed by last one.

If I refresh page (F5) - script works perfectly.

Any helps ? Thanks a lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'a', function () {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr[role="row"]');
  var data = table.row(row).data();
  
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
  $("#email").val(data[0]);
  
  $("#ulozit").click(function(){
    var novy_email = $("#email").val();
     $.ajax
         ({      
             method: "POST",
          url: "action_admin.php?action=uprava_emailu",
          data: { novy_email:novy_email, id:data[3] },
            success: function(data)
      {
       table.ajax.reload();
       $("#myModal").modal("hide");       
      }
         })  
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: your snippet doesn't work. import jQuery and post html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested `onClick` handlers.

The second handler is added every time the first handler is called. The jQuery event model allows multiple handlers on one element, therefore a later handler does not override an older handler. The handlers will execute in the order in which they were bound.

In short: Do not nest your handlers.

Comment: @Fajny_Kubo Nice, that worked better than I expected. The normal response here is always: And how do I do that? But you worked it out yourself. Bravo!